# Connection to remote db2 database through JDBC fails

Tags: jdbc, db2

I am new to db2. I want to ask if it is possible to just connect to a db2 database on a remote db2 server through my java application? Merely having jdbc driver of type 4?

I am having db2jcc4 driver on build path.

When I try this simple code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded");

        try {
            Connection dbConn =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://192.168.0.103:50000/ABC", "****", "*****");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Connection fails with this exception. I am unable to trace what is exactly happening?

```
 com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][10262][11223][4.19.26] Unexpected Throwable caught: null. ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at com.connect.db2.ConnectToServer.main(ConnectToServer.java:22)


 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.q(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.p(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.l(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.d(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.k(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(Unknown Source)
... 12 more
```

Also the db2diag.log after getconnection is :

```
 PID     : 5110                 TID : 140245920114432 PROC : db2sysc 0
 INSTANCE: sachindb             NODE : 000            DB   : ABC
 APPHDL  : 0-46                 APPID: 192.168.0.101.64054.151230182945
 AUTHID  : SACHINDB             HOSTNAME: Sachin
 EDUID   : 22                   EDUNAME: db2agent (ABC) 0
 FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleIsDatabaseDirectoryConnectable, probe:6835
 MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8005006D=-2147155859=SQLE_CA_BUILT
      "SQLCA has been built and saved in component specific control   block."
 DATA #1 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1035   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc: 
 sqlerrp : SQLE534 
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
       (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)    
       (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)     
 sqlstate:
```

Comment: as a sidenote, as of JDBC 4.0 / Java 6, calling `Class.forName()` is no longer necessary

Comment: @Sachin Giri, Did you solve the problem?
Seems that I have exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AES encryption mechanism in Java 7?  If so, I found this solution via Googull at [IBM.com](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21682878)

Otherwise, try creating a DB2SimpleDataSource object directly.

```
private DB2SimpleDataSource db2;
private void configureDataSource() {

     db2 = new DB2SimpleDataSource();
     db2.setServerName("192.168.0.103");
     db2.setPortNumber(50000);
     db2.setDatabaseName("ABC");
     db2.setUser("****");
     db2.setPassword("*****");
     db2.setReadOnly(true);          
}
```

Then connect like this  `Connection c = db2.getConnection()` or this `Connection c = db2.getConnection("****", "*****")`

Also...  See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529163/can-not-connect-to-remote-db2-database-via-jdbc-4-driver?rq=1)

Comment: I can't use type2 driver as it requires some native libraries which are in Db2 data server client. So I can't use above method, I tried it and it gave me differenet exceptions about native libraries. Also I am not using AES encryption. I also tried to putting those unlimited policy jars in my java home/jre/lib/security. But no luck.

Comment: Hmmm.  I use type 4 drivers exclusively, and before obfuscation, the above code came straight out of one of my projects...  But I don't have any experience on the database admin side of this equation.  My company has DBAs who interact directly with DB2, the only way I connect is via JDBC.

Comment: DB2 Command Center uses JDBC under the hood.  Can you connect to your database in Command Center from the box where you are running your JDBC app?